# Java Couchbase: Getting a RejectedExecutionException when trying to close Couchbase DB

Tags: java, junit, couchbase

I'm writing some JUnit tests that involve opening Couchbase, doing some stuff, and then closing Couchbase. The test works in that a connection is established and a bucket is created but then when the cluster is disconnecting an exception occurs. Again, everything seems to work but I'm not sure if the connection is actually getting closed and I'd like to understand why the problem is occurring.

If I toggle on a Thread.sleep for a few seconds the error does not happen. Also if I comment out the opening of the bucket the error does not happen. So I think it has something to do with the bucket needing time to open and do its thing before the cluster is closed (I also tried to close the bucket before closing the cluster but that didn't seem to make a difference).

I'm trying to understand why this is happening and if there is a more elegant way to solve it than using a Thread.sleep.

Here is the code:

```
static Cluster cluster;
static Bucket bucket;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() {
    cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create();
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDown() {
    cluster.disconnect();
}

@Test
public void test() {    
    ClusterManager clusterManager = cluster.clusterManager("Administrator", "***");
    BucketSettings bucketSettings = new DefaultBucketSettings.Builder()
    .type(BucketType.COUCHBASE)
    .name("test_db")
    .password("")
    .quota(100)
    .indexReplicas(true)
    .enableFlush(true)
    .build();
    clusterManager.insertBucket(bucketSettings);
    bucket = cluster.openBucket("test_db");
    //DO DB Operations
    //Thread.sleep(4000);
}
```

Here is the error log:

```
16:55:53.859 [globalEventExecutor-2-3] INFO com.couchbase.client.core.env.CoreEnvironment - Shutdown IoPool: success 
16:55:54.705 [RxComputationScheduler-3] ERROR com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.rejectedExecution - Failed to submit a listener notification task. Event loop shut down?
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: event executor terminated
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.reject(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:796)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.offerTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:336)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.addTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:329)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:739)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.safeExecute(DefaultPromise.java:760)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:428)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure(DefaultPromise.java:113)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.setFailure(DefaultChannelPromise.java:87)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint$3.call(AbstractEndpoint.java:337)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint$3.call(AbstractEndpoint.java:330)
    at rx.internal.operators.SingleOperatorOnErrorResumeNext$2.onError(SingleOperatorOnErrorResumeNext.java:69)
    at rx.internal.operators.SingleTimeout$TimeoutSingleSubscriber$OtherSubscriber.onError(SingleTimeout.java:133)
    at rx.Single$1.call(Single.java:460)
    at rx.Single$1.call(Single.java:456)
    at rx.internal.operators.SingleTimeout$TimeoutSingleSubscriber.call(SingleTimeout.java:110)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.EventLoopsScheduler$EventLoopWorker$2.call(EventLoopsScheduler.java:189)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16:55:54.706 [RxComputationScheduler-3] DEBUG com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.Endpoint - [null][KeyValueEndpoint]: Endpoint connect completed, but got instructed to disconnect in the meantime.
16:55:54.821 [Thread-5] INFO com.couchbase.client.core.env.CoreEnvironment - Shutdown Netty: failure 
16:55:54.821 [Thread-5] INFO com.couchbase.client.core.env.CoreEnvironment - Netty shutdown is best effort, ignoring failure
```

Thanks for any help/suggestions!

Comment: It's not clear from your question what operation is causing the exception, since you haven't included them. The message makes it seems like operations are in-flight when you close the connection. Presumably you have some facility to wait for them to complete. As a general comment, this sort of thing usually doesn't go in a unit test.

Comment: I'm not doing any operations. The comment is just a place holder for the DB operations that would follow. The code as is causes the error. In regards to to your general comment, yeah was sort of getting that feeling. Is this because I shouldn't be doing all this db work in a unit test? Seems like it's more integration level testing. I was just trying to figure out how to test a class/method that requires a bucket as one of its parameters. Not sure how to make a mock bucket and test it without actually creating a real bucket. Thanks for the help.